# Layout and Text problems on Blender meta

Tags: discussion, bug, status-reproduced, meta

I have just asked my first question on Blender meta, and when I tried to submit it I got an error:

[image]

First, it said '…see the error above.' but there was no error 'above'! The red 'flag thingy', to the right, said 'At least one of these tags is required - 'bug feature-request discussion support' (like a sentence rather than a list of tags). To someone new, this doesn't really make sense! I clicked on it hoping the error 'above' might appear to help me understand…do you understand my point? Luckily I managed to figure it out and I hope I'm not being too picky. :)

This time I'll make sure I add one of those 'odd' words to my Tags - before submitting.

Comment: I *think* the error message might be referring to the outlined box..

Comment: I have added the tag 'bug' thanks to Luke's suggestion

Answer (score -2):

Every question on meta should fall into one of those three categories. It is mainly to keep everything organized. Because of that, the system requires every meta question to contain at least one of these tags.

> [discussion](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion)
>
> designed to solicit opinions or best-practices on a particular topic, with the goal of reaching community consensus.

> [bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug)
>
> Indicates you've found an erroneous or unexpected behaviour in the system that needs to be fixed.

> [support](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support)
>
> You need help with the use of one or more of the site's features.

> [feature-request](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)
>
> You have an idea for a new feature, or for a change to the existing functionality.

Comment: I don't think he was really looking for an explanation of the tags, just that it was a bit confusing what to do at that point but it's a good read nonetheless.

Comment: @iKlsR yes you're right, the point I was trying to make  was that the words: 'bug feature-request discussion support'- are all bunched together with nothing to indicate that they should be read as separate 'tags'.

Comment: I see. In that case, this question should be tagged with [bug] (because the tags should at least be separated by commas).

Comment: @SteveW this isn't too bad, if you click in the tag box, it should prompt you with options.

Comment: @iKlsR maybe it should say: 'Click in the tag box for options' then?

Comment: @Luke yes, commas, I was hoping someone would pick up on that. :)